# android how to communicate android navigation items to fragment(just like menu)

Tags: android, fragment

Hello all I just have a simple question but I couldn't find the suitable solution.
When I create an navigation drawer activity in android it contains menu items inside drawer.Now I just removed all the menu items and replaced my main layout file with following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
    <ReletiveLayout    
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_dashboard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <FrameLayout  
            android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBar"> 
            </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#23282e"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

     <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/dashboard_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:background="#2e353d"
                        android:layout_height="35dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/dashboard"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:text="Dashboard"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
     </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now i want to swtich the fragment onclicking to the Linearlayout(dashboard).Using menu it is usually done inside onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item).How can I do this without using menuitem.

Answer (score 0):

set an `OnclickListner` to the LinearLayout and in it's `OnClick` method change the Fragment..

Comment: can you please suggest how to do so?